# How can I prevent a specific item from being downloaded from my html file? (<input type="file">)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to "convert" a lot of mp3 files to html players, and I want to have other people (lay people) doing it in an easy way. So after this, I can download each player with its own mp3 embeded.

I am using the following code for this, the idea is that someone upload the mp3 file, download the page (to have the player functional embeded with mp3), but, when I download the page, does not bring the input button ***input type="file"***.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<audio controls id="myAudio" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay></audio>

<script>
var $audio = $('#myAudio');
$('input').on('change', function(e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var file = target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  
  console.log($audio[0]);
   if (target.files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $audio.attr('src', e.target.result);
            $audio.play();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "accept" attribute to the input tag.

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp3" />
```

Comment: That works but be aware of what browsers you plan to support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept

Comment: The OP says "but, when I download the page, does not bring the input button input type='file'". I'm not sure how limiting the file input to only accept mp3 files achieves that.